# @JsonFormat not working in nested object

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a very simple bean:

```
public class StatusBean {

 private String name;
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy")
 private Date startDate;
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy")
 private Date endDate;

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
 public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
 }
 public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
 }
 public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
 }
 public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
 }
}
```

And I wrap it in another bean that I use to wrap objects for nice json formatting with messages and stuff:

```
public class ResponseBean {

private boolean success = false;
private String message;
private Object data;

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}
public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public Object getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

In my controller, I set the Status bean inside the response bean with a setData();

Spring serializes this out in JSON format,  however the output for the date is not formatting. I am getting the standard "yyyy-MM-DD" format.

Am I doing something wrong?  How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are you using java.util.Date?

Comment: Yes I am.  Should I be using something else?

Comment: no. I asked because in many articles people pointed that @JsonFormat does not work with java.sql.Date. So I decided to check this)

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak: There is an issue about the java.sql.Date problem: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1407
mmaceachran: maybe at runtime your Dates are java.sql.Date after all? Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and fixed simply adding `@JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)` before `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="MM-dd-yyyy")`

Answer (score 3):

With `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")` from 
`org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried it but the solution could be to add this annotation in your ResponseBean:

```
@JsonSerialize(as = StatusBean.class)
private Object data;
```

unfortunately your Object will become a StatusBean

Answer (score 0):

Possibility not write object with **ObjectMapper**

```java
new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(MyObject);
```

Full code example

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(new java.util.Date())));
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))));
    }

    static class Foo {

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", timezone="EST")
        private Date birthdate;

        public Foo() {

        }

        public Foo(Date birthdate) {
            this.birthdate = birthdate;
        }

        public Date getBirthdate() {
            return birthdate;
        }

    }
```